# ng-change function gets run on page load before data loads?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

One of my controller functions gets run before my data loads.

The html:

```
<div ng-show="item.name">
    <input ng-change="doChange()" ng-model="item.name">
</div>
```

My controller:

```
$scope.item = { name: 'bob' };
$scope.other = {};

$scope.doChange = function() {
    $scope.item = $scope.other['test'].name
}

// load the data now!
MyService.getData().success(function(newdata) {
    $scope.item = newdata.item;
    $scope.other = newdata.other;
});
```

My Service:

```
app.factory("MyService", function($http) {
    return {
        getData: function() {
            return $http.get("/data");
        }
    }
});
```

This results in

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

because `doChange()` gets executed before the service has loaded the data. I'm not sure why this happens. Shouldn't `doChange` only run when the input has changed, yet it's getting run on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it turns out elsewhere in the code I had changed `item.name` which was why it was being launched on page load.

I had thought `ng-model` was somehow triggering `ng-change` on the `<input>`, but it was me just being foolish.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$scope.doChange() {
  $scope.item = $scope.other['test'].name
}
```

to

```
$scope.doChange = function() {
  $scope.item = $scope.other['test'].name
}
```